# Vue-Multiselect - Set value to an attribute of the object instead of the entire object

Tags: vue.js, vue-multiselect

I am using vue-multiselect with an array of objects which is working just fine. However, I need to pull the ID from the object to use in order for the API to accept the format.

For example, I can handle this format just fine:

```html
<script>
{// person
   id: 1
   shirt: {
      id: 1
      color: 'blue'
   }
}
</script>
// in my html, this works well, but I'd like to do formData.person.shirt_id and have multiselect set the id from the entire object instead of setting the entire object.
<multiselect
    v-model="formData.person.shirt" 
    :options="shirts" 
    :searchable="true"
    placeholder="Select a shirt">
</multiselect>
```

But I'm looking to set "shirt_id" instead of an entire shirt object.

Is there a simple solution to do something like this with vue-multiselect?